# Selenium wait for user captcha input C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and using C# for a login page which consists of Username, Password and Captcha. 
Problem is, for Captcha code It has to wait for user input and submit the form manually.
I don't know what solution is correct on this issue. 
Is there any better way please ?

This is my code.

```
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://someonewebite.com/");

        IWebElement usernameInput = driver.FindElement(By.Name("txtUserName"));
        IWebElement passwordInput = driver.FindElement(By.Name("txtPassword"));

        usernameInput.SendKeys("username");
        passwordInput.SendKeys("password");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        wait.Until((d) =>
        {
            return (bool)((RemoteWebDriver)d).ExecuteScript("return document.body.className.match(/\submittedpage\b/).length");
        });
```

Comment: Could you please define how you want the user to input the captcha data? maybe you can fetch the image and show it in a UserControl opened as a dialog? This way the main thread will be blocked until the form is closed.

Comment: So you just want to wait for the CAPTCHA to be displayed? The most you can do is wait for it's underlying element's to be displayed, but this doesn't mean that the actual text inside it is there. In some CAPTCHA's they can just put an element in the DOM and fill it in with an async request. So you've got no sure fire way of saying "is this CAPTCHA there and does it have something inside it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach with the WebDriverWait is a good one if you cannot login without manual interaction – why do you want to change it?
But you don’t have to use JavaScript to identify if you have logged in successfully. It is also possible to use any WebDriver Method in the predicate passed to wait.Until().
Thus you could also do the following:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
wait.Until((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(…); // here you can use any locator that identifies a successful / failed login
});
```

Answer (score 3):

We cannot Automate Captcha in selenium as far i know...The main advantage of captcha is that it cannot be break by any automation Language and thats why it is used for.

Comment: I dont wanna pass the Captcha, I want to wait for user Capcha code and submit the form manually.

Comment: Just to make sure i am understanding you in right way  Can you implement Thread.sleep(5000);  Can you use Manual Wait after you pass the sendKeys() to username and password input fields?